# Tenant Schema Extension App missing from Enterprise Applications in our Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I am following this doc to map a directory schema extension attribute created with AD Connect to my custom claims emitted in the Open ID token:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions

It references the following doc on how such attributes are supposed to be named using the special `extension_[app_id]_[attr_name]` convention where `app_id` belongs to the special Enterprise Application called **Tenant Schema Extension App** that is supposed to have been installed during the installation of AD Connect:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions

However, this app doesn't exist in our case, nor is there any other application with the word "tenant" in its name:

[image]

Why is it missing? Can it be added post-factum? What are my options at this point?

I am not the one who set up our Azure AD or installed AD Connect, it was done by another team who could not answer my questions, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

We use Azure AD Connect directory extensions to extend the schema in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with your own attributes from on-premises Active Directory. For that we need to use customize synchronization options
To do that Run Azure AD Connect Wizard.>>Click on Customize>>Provide Azure AD Credentials and at ‘Optional Features’ page, we need to turn on ‘Directory Extension Attribute Sync’ feature once we enable and perform the sync to azure ad The "Tenant Schema Extension App" application will be created. May be this option is not enabled in your case so try to enable that option  and see if it creates the app in azure ad.

Comment: Thank you @JayakrishnaGunnam-MT!  But how do I run the AD Connect wizard?  I don't see the link/button anywhere in our Azure AD portal.